# Compile/Save/Export HTML as a PNG Image using Jquery

Tags: jquery, screenshot, capture

I have a set-up with multiple variables that users can alter that effect a visual representation of an element. All of this is controlled by jquery scripts. It would be cool if there was a way to save the resultant image as per what the browser renders. It'd be no different than a screencapture from a user perspective, though it would only capture the relevant area.

I have a plugin for FF called Page Saver, and it's functionality is pretty much what i am looking for, but with jquery or regular javascript if possible.

I'm more asking for tips, and a general direction that you guys would advise me to go in in order to pursue such functionality. I'd prefer not to learn another language to do this, but if i must...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Edit : This method only works in Firefox extensions.

You can use [HTML5 canvas](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-canvas-element.html), Firefox' [drawWindow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/CanvasRenderingContext2D#drawWindow()) and the [toDataURL](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-canvas-element.html#dom-canvas-todataurl) method. For example:

```
var capture = function() {
  var root = document.documentElement;
  var canvas = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'html:canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var selection = {
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: root.scrollWidth,
    height: root.scrollHeight,
  };

  canvas.height = selection.height;
  canvas.width = selection.width;

  context.drawWindow(
    window,
    selection.left,
    selection.top,
    selection.width,
    selection.height,
    'rgb(255, 255, 255)'
  );

  return canvas.toDataURL('image/png', '');
};
```

You can adjust `top`, `left`, `width` and `height` to capture only a part of the web page.

The result is a [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) string. You can send it to your server or draw it on another canvas:

```
  var canvas = document.getElementById('captured');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = capture();

  // the image is not immediately usable
  $(image).load(function() { // jquery way
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  });
```

Your plugin probably uses this method. You can also check its source code.

**Edit**: To send it to your server with JQuery you can do something like that:

```
$("#send-capture-button").click(function() {
  $.post("/url-to-send-image-to", {image_data: capture()})
});
```

On the server side you'll have to decode the data URL.

Comment: Wow, I'll have o play around with this and see if I cant get it to do what I need. Thanks for the very indepth answer! This uses HTML5, so only newer browsers will be able to employ such functionality?

Comment: You can check http://caniuse.com/#search=canvas but I don't know if the "canvas basic support" includes this method.

Comment: It took me a while before i was ready to implement this script. I'm not sure how to implement it though, how do i trigger the image creation, and where would the resultant image show up?

Comment: could you clarify what html structure i'd need for this?

Comment: You don't need any HTML structure (except if you want to use the sample that draws the image on the document, then you'd need a `<canvas id="captured"/>` somewhere on the page). I added a sample to send the image to your server.

Comment: this does not work: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<CanvasRenderingContext2D> has no method 'drawWindow' look:http://jsbin.com/oribiy/1/edit

Comment: You're right. [It only works in Firefox extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/CanvasRenderingContext2D#drawWindow()). I edited the answer.

Comment: does it have to be canvas or does it also work for any HTML element?

Answer (score 0):

There is no JS functionality built into browsers that would allow you turn an image into HTML sadly.  So you would need something like a browser plugin or extension installed that has a JS API that you can call into.  But even then, it would obviously require that plugin be installed on that persons browser.