# How can I save any selected range of my webpage to image?

Tags: jquery

What kind of technology can I use to do the following operation?
I don't wish to download additional plugin like active X and install Java.

After I open my webpage, I need to select any rectangle range using mouse, then clicking a button on the webpage I'd like to save the selected range to image.

Can JQuery do that?

Comment: Is the web page running on your domain, or do you mean arbitrary web sites? (I'm not sure whether it's possible either way, but the former is definitely more likely)

Comment: Well, there is no way to do this without *some* additional software. The page needs to be rendered, and then you need to save the image.  On the client side, the only way to do this would be using the Print Screen key.

Comment: To Pekka: The webpage is running om my domain, I can add any server and client code to the webpage!

Answer (score 0):

Ive not seen anything like this around, obviously mac computers have this by default with cmd shift 4.

What I have seen is http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/jquery-image-crop-plugin-jcrop/ which seems to have the functionality you need however for images so maby you can modify it to your needs.

Comment: To Dominic Green: Thanks! I need to select any rectangle range of the webpage, not only picture , but also text, and can save the selected any rectangle range to a image at client browser.

Comment: Yer i mentioned that the solution may need some work, The only other solution that may work is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941631/compile-save-export-html-as-a-png-image-using-jquery